# RFC 6241 interpretation related to file:// URI

Tags: ietf-netmod-yang, ietf-netconf, netconf, yang

The Netconf RFC 6241 provides an example like shown below.

```
 <rpc message-id="101"
      xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
   <copy-config>
     <target>
       <url>file://checkpoint.conf</url>
     </target>
     <source>
       <running/>
     </source>
   </copy-config>
 </rpc>
```

But it does not clearly explain how to interpret the URI file://checkpoint.conf. I see some implementations refers to this file under root '/', some refers to this file under current working directory. Some failed too in interpreting this. I see RFC 8089 does not clearly explain this relative pathing. Any one has idea on how to interpret this?

-Ram

Comment: I'd say it is up to each implementation to define the meaning of a relative URI like this (and should also document it). Not all NETCONF devices support a file system and terms like "root" and "current working directory" may not be applicable to them at all, but can still "understand" the `file:` URI scheme - perhaps it's pointing to a flat file database on some chip somewhere in a highly platform specific way. All of this is just conjecture, so I'm intentionally not putting it into an answer.